# Google Custom Search on submit

Tags: javascript, search

I would like to customize my search form. I am using Google Search Service and have it linked to my domain and so on.

I chose the two column layout in the Control Panel, but however, I want to do something onSubmit of the form.

So I tried to put an actionlistener in jQuery into the form, however does not work.

Then I thought google certainly provides something for that. And yes they do. It is called:

```
setOnSubmitCallback()
```

http://code.google.com/apis/websearch/docs/reference.html

Unfortunately I dont get it.

So far I have:

```
google.load('search', '1', {language : 'en', style : google.loader.themes.MINIMALIST});

                    function initialize()
                    {
                        var searchControl = new google.search.CustomSearchControl('017998360718714977594:j6sbtr-d6x8');
                        searchControl.setResultSetSize(google.search.Search.FILTERED_CSE_RESULTSET);

                        var options = new google.search.DrawOptions();
                        options.setSearchFormRoot('cse-search-form');

                        searchControl.draw('cse', options);
                    }

                    google.setOnLoadCallback(initialize);
```

So i have two divs: 
`#cse-search-form` for the form and `#cse` for the results

`#cse` is in another div #searchResults, that is hidden and here it comes:

I want to open #searchResults in a dialog from jQuery UI.

```
$("#searchResults").dialog( { minWidth: 750, minHeight: 750 } );
```

Which will result into:

```
.setOnSubmitCallback(function() {
    $("#searchResults").dialog( { minWidth: 750, minHeight: 750 } );
} );
```

So my problem now is, where and on what do I have to put the setOnSubmitCallback?

I cannot put it on google.search.Search or CustomSearchControl as it is stated in the documentation. ANd I cannot call it in the onLoadCallback so it is very strange for me. Cannt figure out how to do that.

I hope somebody has some more experience for the google search and could help me out with a solution.

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

NOTE: the code below is using something Google deprecated.  Use this instead: http://code.google.com/apis/customsearch/v1/overview.html

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <title>Hello World - Google  Web Search API Sample</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.11/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
    <script src="https://www.google.com/jsapi" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script language="Javascript" type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
    google.load('search', '1');
    google.load("jquery", "1.5.2");
    google.load("jqueryui", "1.8.12");

    function OnLoad() {

        var searchComplete = function(searchControl, searcher){
            $('#searchResults').dialog({modal: true, width: 700, height: 400, position: [50, 50]});
            for (result in searcher.results) {
                var content = searcher.results[result].content;
                var title = searcher.results[result].title;
                var url = searcher.results[result].url;
                $('#searchResults ul')
                    .append($('<li></li>')
                        .append($('<a/>').attr('href', url).text(title))
                        .append($('<p/>').text(content)));
            }
        };

        // called on form submit
        newSearch = function(form) {
          if (form.input.value) {
            // Create a search control
            var searchControl = new google.search.SearchControl();

            // Add in a set of searchers
            searchControl.addSearcher(new google.search.WebSearch());
            searchControl.addSearcher(new google.search.VideoSearch());

            // tell the searchControl to draw itself (without this, the searchComplete won't get called - I'm not sure why)
            searchControl.draw();

            searchControl.setLinkTarget(google.search.Search.LINK_TARGET_SELF);           
            searchControl.setSearchCompleteCallback(this, searchComplete);
            searchControl.execute(form.input.value);
          }
          return false;
        }

        // create a search form without a clear button
        // bind form submission to my custom code
        var container = document.getElementById("searchFormContainer");
        this.searchForm = new google.search.SearchForm(false, container);
        this.searchForm.setOnSubmitCallback(this, newSearch);
    }
    google.setOnLoadCallback(OnLoad);

    //]]>
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="searchFormContainer">Loading</div>
    <div id="searchResults" title="Search Results">
        <ul></ul>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: OK - that would lead me to this code:

http://pastebin.com/0eMBHzTh

I can search and it shows me my dialog on the submit. However, It is not going to show me the results.

Comment: Ok, I whipped up a fully working example.  It's a little convoluted, thanks for helping me not be lazy and figure it out.

Comment: WoW Milimetric, thats just great work! I didnt expect somebody to write that. The code is fine and I do understand it. But - because there is always a but - It is just a google search - not a search on my website. It is not connected with a google search account. That is my main problem. I am going to bed now, but I will have a look at it later today and might be able to edit your script to connect it to my google account for the search engine that it uses my website to search on.
Thanks again! I appreciate that a lot.

Comment: I think the answer to that is just adding another searcher.  So right now it's searching Video and Web by adding `new google.search.WebSearch()` and `new google.search.VideoSearch()` with `searchControl.addSearcher`.  So, to do a search on your site, I think just add your ?key=YOUR-KEY when you reference https://www.google.com/jsapi, and then add the right searcher (don't know what that is).  Hey, btw, I'm dumb but I just realized this is deprecated.  You should be using: http://code.google.com/apis/customsearch/v1/overview.html
            searchControl.addSearcher();

Comment: `var searchControl = new google.search.CustomSearchControl('017998360718714977594:j6sbtr-d6x8');

            // Add in a set of searchers
   var webSearch = new google.search.WebSearch();
   webSearch.setSiteRestriction("http://www.wimbledon-it.co.uk");
            searchControl.addSearcher(webSearch);`
Should make it now!

Comment: Yep, there you go.  But do check out that newer API, it looks a lot friendlier.